# Degree of the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial of degree three

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $f(x)=x^3-px+q$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Denote its complex zeros by $a_1, a_2, a_3$. Define $\det(f)=(a_1-a_2)^2(a_2-a_3)^2(a_3-a_1)^2$. It turns out $\det(f)=4p^3-27q^2$, which is rational.

Denote $K=\mathbb Q(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, a field extension of the rationals.

I've already proven that: $\det(f) \neq 0$, $[K:\mathbb Q]=3$ or $6$, which turns out by the theorem for towers of fields to depend on $[\mathbb Q(a_1,a_2):\mathbb Q(a_1)]$, which equals $1$ or $2$.

> Question: Prove that $\sqrt{\det(f)}\notin\mathbb Q$ $\implies$ $[K:\mathbb Q]=6$.

I tried proving this, but I couldn't do it. I could do it directly or by contraposition.
Could somebody help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** It follows from the definition that $\sqrt{\mathrm{Det}(f)}=|(a_1-a_2)(a_2-a_3)(a_3-a_1)|\in K$. Now use the fact that $\mathrm{Det}(f)\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already did that first step, but I don't really know where to go then.

Comment: I've added an extra line. Does that help?

Comment: Not really. Sorry. I could see why the dimension $[K:Q]>1$ because of that, but not why it should be six. Or why $[Q(a_1,a_2):Q(a_1)]$ should be two.

Comment: What is the degree of $L:=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\mathrm{Det}(f)})$ over $\mathbb Q$? Note that $L$ is a subfield of $K$.

Comment: Two? Since $(x^2-Det(f))$ is a minimal polynomial of degree $2$? Wait... I have an idea. Can I then say that I should add more elements to get to $K$, but the index can never be three, because of the theorem for towers of fields?

Comment: Exactly. Or you could even say, again by the tower theorem, that $2\mid [K:\mathbb Q]$, which can only happen if it is $6$